# Drag Back to same position

Tags: iphone, ios

Im using drag option in my application, Since i want to  set the object in the same position, that is after drag back to same position, I tried with following coding it sets to som other postion, What change should i made in this,

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
CGPoint touchPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
if (touchPoint.x > self.img1.frame.origin.x &&
    touchPoint.x < self.img1.frame.origin.x + self.img1.frame.size.width &&
    touchPoint.y > self.img1.frame.origin.y &&
    touchPoint.y < self.img1.frame.origin.y + self.img1.frame.size.height )
{
    self.img1.backgroundColor = self.img1.backgroundColor;

}
self.img1.frame = CGRectMake(self.homePosition.x, self.homePosition.y,
                                   self.img1.frame.size.width,
                                   self.img1.frame.size.height);
}
```

Comment: In `touchBeginEvent` store the starting value into the variable then use it..

Comment: @MountainLion any references is available huh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `.h`

CGPoint startPt;

In `.m`

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    startPt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];

}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
CGPoint touchPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
if (touchPoint.x > self.img1.frame.origin.x &&
    touchPoint.x < self.img1.frame.origin.x + self.img1.frame.size.width &&
    touchPoint.y > self.img1.frame.origin.y &&
    touchPoint.y < self.img1.frame.origin.y + self.img1.frame.size.height )
{
    self.img1.backgroundColor = self.img1.backgroundColor;

}
self.img1.frame = CGRectMake(startPt.x, startPt.y,
                                   self.img1.frame.size.width,
                                   self.img1.frame.size.height);
}
```